# Bound on Difference Between Sum of Probabilities

Tags: probability, inequality, boundary-value-problem

I have the following probability equation:
$$\hat{T}(x,a,x')=T(x,a,x') + \epsilon(x,a,x')$$ for all $x,x'\in X$ and $a \in A$, and $0 \leq T(x,a,x') \leq 1$. and
$$P(x) = \max_{a \in A} \sum_{x' \in X}T(x,a,x')P(x').$$ and $$\hat{P}(x) = \max_{a \in A} \sum_{x' \in X}\hat{T}(x,a,x') \hat{P}(x').$$ for all $x \in X$ where $0 \leq P(x,a,x') \leq 1$.
I want to find a bound $\delta(x)$ on the absolute difference $|\hat{P}(x) - P(x)|$ such that $|\hat{P}(x) - P(x)| \leq \delta(x)$. Obviously, $\delta(x) \leq 1$ but how can I proceed to find a tighter bound and express $\delta(x)$ in terms of $\epsilon(x,a,x')$? Please assume all the sets are finite.

Comment: Is A a finite set?

Comment: Also what is $\hat{P}$

Comment: Yes, all the sets are finite. And $\hat{P}(x) = \max_{a} \sum_{x'} \hat{T} (x,a,x')   \hat{P} (x')$. Thanks!